# Dynamic Construction of enum with an other enum

Tags: c#, wcf, constructor, enums

I have a wcf service which use an other wcf service (on the web). 
This other wcf service has an enum.

I would that my client depends only on my wcf service. 
So, I would that my wcf service has an enum with values of enum of the other wcf service.

How create my enum with values of the other wcf service 's enum ?

Comment: The whole point of using enums is to assign compile-time "names" to numbers (and occasionally to combine them using binary operations). Therefore, the idea of dynamically constructing an `enum` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are serializable, so just deserialize the  WSDL.

Use `Add Service Reference` and enter the URL of the WSDL.  VS will generate the interface for you.

If you change the interface, then of cause you'll break the clients and they'll need updating.

Comment: I don't understand how I must do for deserialize the WSDL ?

Comment: The WSDL defines your interface, which would include the enum, so construct your interface as you usually would do from the WSDL.  There shouldn't be any reason for dynamic compilation.

Comment: The web service is : [link](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL) . I have all enum values with : `ServiceConversionDevise.Currency.GetValues(typeof(ServiceConversionDevise.Currency)).Cast<ServiceConversionDevise.Currency>();` Where and when I must deserialize the WSDL ?

Comment: The easiest way (VS 2010) is to right click on the project in the `Solution Explorer`, select `Add Service Reference`, you'll be presented with a dialogue box, enter `http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx` as the address, give it a namespace and click OK.  VS will generate the interface for you, including the Enum `Currency`, with all the values.